# Linux WiFI AP : refresh `iw dev wlan0 station dump` output (inactive time)

Tags: linux, networking, wifi

- I have a Linux (3.14.36) embedded board acting as a WiFi AP.
- The WiFi chipset doesn't support monitoring mode.
- My laptop(the client) is connected to this board by WiFi
- The WiFi AP is acting as a network bridge to another computer, and doesn't provide an IP adress to the client (the WiFi AP only has the MAC address of the client)

I want to monitor the signal strengh of the connection WiFi AP <-> Client and be able to trigger a "refresh" of the signal strengh value.

Doing : `iw dev wlan0 station dump` gives me :

```
Station xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (on wlan0)
    inactive time:  123820 ms // <-- The problem
    rx bytes:   10291
    rx packets: 60
    ...
    signal:     -65 dBm // What I want to refresh
    ...
```

I understood that the signal strengh is updated every time there is a network activity. (So, in the example above, it has been refreshed 123s ago).

How can I force a refresh of this value ? (By forcing the AP to send "something" to the client for example) Knowing that the board/WiFi driver/WiFi device doesn't support tools such as iwconfig

Answer (score 4):

*For anyone finding this thread now:*

I had this issue and my solution was to ping the device before doing the iw dump, e.g.

Get the list of of connected MAC addresses:

```
iw dev wlan0 station dump | grep 'signal' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Then get the IP address from these MAC addresses *(alternatively you could use **arp**)*:

```
ip neigh | grep 'ma:ca:dd:re:ss:ss' | awk '{print $1}'
```

Then ping each of those:

```
ping -c 1 'IP.address'
```

Then get the refreshed signal for that MAC address

```
iw dev wlan0 station get 'ma:ca:dd:re:ss:ss' | grep 'signal' | awk '{print $2}'
```

I wrapped all this up in a Python script and it seemed to give reliable data.

Comment: Use `iw dev wlan0 station dump | grep 'Station' | awk '{print $2}'` for getting list of MAC address

Answer (score 2):

I'll give it a try:

You're embedded so I guess you have `busybox`. You have no IP but you may then use `arping` (if this applet is not configured in your busybox build, change the config) to send something small and useless that may wake up the thing. What IP to use for your ARP requests? Well it seems you can use a "dummy" IP.

I'm running this on a PC but I do have busybox with its arping, and I use a wired interface, but here is the concept:

```
jbm@sumo:~/sandbox/iw$ sudo busybox arping -w 1 -U -I eth0 0.0.0.0
ARPING to 0.0.0.0 from 192.168.1.66 via eth0
Sent 2 probe(s) (2 broadcast(s))
Received 0 reply (0 request(s), 0 broadcast(s))
```

The useful thing is that though the "dummy" IP, I can check with `tcpdump` that the arp requests do actually go on the wire (or in the air in your case):

```
jbm@sumo:~$ sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -v arp
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
10:42:20.111100 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 0.0.0.0 (Broadcast) tell sumo, length 28
10:42:21.111206 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 0.0.0.0 (Broadcast) tell sumo, length 28
^C
2 packets captured
2 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

So sending ARP request on your wireless interface may be enough to "wake up" your connection and refresh your RSSI.

EDIT:

See the interesting uses and properties of IP 0.0.0.0 here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0

EDIT 2:

Re-thinking about it, I realized there will be a problem if your wireless interface does not have an IP itself. Which, if I'm not mistaking, may not necessarily be case in your bridging configuration. In such case, `arping` will not have a source address to build its request packets (nor will know how to listen for responses), and will fail.

*But* you can create your own "mini-unidirectional arping", using an `AF_PACKET` socket and build your own ARP request packet with a dummy/random source IP address. It will be unidirectional because the response to your forged ARP request, if any, would go to to the random source IP which may and preferably should not exist. But it the principle of just awaking your wireless connection by sending "something", that may do the trick.

For inspiration on how to code this "mini-unidirectional arping", have a look at busybox implementation from its udhcpc/udhcpd (it's simpler than the full-blown arping busybox applet):

https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/udhcp/arpping.c#n38

The `from_ip` parameter is what you want to forge. You can use your actual MAC as `from_mac`, just for the sake of dignity :-) You don't even have to wait for a response (starting line 89), so that would be something like 50 lines of C code + a little main if you want to add a few options to it.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your answer. Network is not my main subject  so thank you for going that much into details, it really helped :).
```busybox arping -w 1 -U -I wlan0 0.0.0.0
arping: can't connect to remote host (0.0.0.0): Invalid argument``` I guess it's because of the problem you explain in your ```ÈDIT 2```. I tried to craft an ARP request with a python RAW socket but the device doesn't reply (but it receive it) so it's not enough to trigger a refresh of the signal. Now i'm trying to craft a RARP request and then I'll try the solution in ```Edit 2``` unless I can find something a easier

Comment: You're welcome. I'd be really interested in knowing if your hypothesis  of "RSSI not refreshed because of inactive time" is valid, and if/how you could validate/invalidate it and workaround to solve it (or fail).Gee... Python on an embedded system... that's _way_ too easy :-) Back in the days, I barely had "1" and "0". And sometime I didn't get "0" and had to use the letter "o".